# Missing primary topmost Xcode6 menu toolbar (File, Edit, Navigate, etc.)

Tags: xcode

I'm using Xcode 6. For some reason the Xcode menu toolbar at the top with everything from File to Navigate and Debug is missing. I've managed without so far but would like to find out if there is an easy fix. Not sure if it was there when I first installed. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I solved this one. It wasn't showing as I had made the window smaller to use alongside online tutorial. When I opened it in full window mode the top toolbar was back.

Answer (score 0):

Try `View > Show Toolbar` to make it re-appear. If this is not the toolbar you miss, please post a screenshot of your current Xcode interface.

Before:
[image: Without toolbar]

Comment: It's the topmost toolbar I am missing - the one with File, Edit, View, Find, Navigate.

Comment: Did you try to reboot your computer? It's by default impossible to hide this bar cause it's managed by the system...

Comment: Yep, we rebooted yesterday evening. Same as before. Might have to reinstall it but I think I'll contact Apple and ask them.